# How to run tens of thousands concurrent transactions on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, r2dbc-postgresql

Many of modern programming languages use lightweight threads (virtual threads/coroutines/goroutines) and thus scalability does not limited by number of threads anymore.

But if these lightweight threads interact with PostgreSQL and start transactions than the limit is a connection pool. Is there a way to run tens of thousands transactions? Maybe by using a single given connection for several concurrent transactions, started by lightweight threads? Maybe it can be achieved with r2dbc?

Is there any other DMBS that allow such a behaviour (if is not possible with PostgreSQL)?

Comment: Transactions and connections are not the same thing. You will need to provide a more detailed description of you want to achieve and why? Actual code would be best. **Add as text update to question text**.

Comment: You cannot have 10000 statements concurrently, but if they are fast enough, you can process them in a split second.

Comment: And, finally thousands of lightweight threads *without* shared mutable state mostly. Everything gets more complicated once you bring state into the picture.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe you totally right that if work done by a thread is fast enough than a connection pool is not a limit. But if work takes say 50ms than a single connection can be used only with 20rps which does not look cool.

It's is more theoretical question than a practical one. It is caused by thought that programming languages try to do their best utilizing multi-core processors, but achieved parallelism is limited by a connection pool.

What other DBMS would you recommend to work in a such scenario?

Comment: There is no problem with parallelization in PostgreSQL, but parallelization doesn't offer unbounded scaling. If you have 48 cores, you cannot expect 10000 concurrent processes to perform well. That's not a shortcoming of PostgreSQL; all systems will have more or less the same problem. It's physics.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from implementing your own "green thread" approach by creating a connection pool of 100 connections or whatever and have some service post data through the connection and then call the service from 100k threads. If you don't need to wait for results it's even better. SQL Server have something called MARS which allows doing multiple request on same connection which might get you even further, although it's not supported through pure jdbc. But as other's said, usually you will hit some sort of limit in the database handling, because of locks, index update times etc